# Add blob storage as input to stream analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-blob-storage

I have an IoThub trigger Azure function app which outputs its data to blob storage, the blob storage is connected to stream analytics job, and the output of this job goes to Powerbi for visualization, I checked my blob storage "butterflycontainer/nodecurrentstatus" and see my data successfully written, the problem is that I can't see any input or output events at stream analytics job, nothing triggered , no datasets created at powerbi, why? and when I press test for input of stream analytics I got,
Successful connection test
Connection to input 'nodecurrentstatusin' succeeded.

but when press sample data input, I got the below error,

No events found for 'nodecurrentstatusin'
No events found for 'nodecurrentstatusin'. Start time: Monday, November 6, 2017, 6:10:05 PM End time: Monday, November 6, 2017, 6:15:05 PM Last time arrival: Thursday, January 1, 1970, 2:00:00 AM Diagnostics: While sampling data, no data was received from '1' partitions.

find also below paths, for my setup,

IotHub
ButteryFly.azure-devices.net

Function App
https://butteryflyfnapp.azurewebsites.net
function name "Nodes_Current_State_Report_Fn_App"
in this function I write to my blob storage using the below code

```js
var strings = JSON.stringify(tableentr); 

blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText(
    containername,
    'nodecurrentstatus',
    strings,
    function(error, result, response){
        if(error){
            console.log("Couldn't upload string");
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('String uploaded successfully');
        }
    });
```

Blob path
https://butterflystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/butterflycontainer/nodecurrentstatus

Stream Analytics job - RESOURCE ID
/subscriptions/f80e5865-d8c1-4ac7-b102-ff72bdbe1188/resourceGroups/IotHub/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/butterfly_streamanalytics

Comment: I fix **"No events found"** issue by making the start time of sampling input data to be the same of last modified blob time, which I noticed it before the start time with about 3 min, so when the sampling start I make sure it will sample the modification update of my blob

Comment: I noticed no datasets created at powerbi, and no job run , no output event on log of stream analytics, but when I created myself at powerbi a dataset with the same name of stream analytics output dataset, dataset created and appended with the real value from my blob, and accordingly I found an output event at stream analytics, Id on't know how it works?